# Performance of a self join in a temporal table with a single day's difference between end_date and start_date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, temporal-tables

Title says it all really. A pretty standard temporal table design has a `start_date` and an `end_date` where the `end_date` is the day before the next record's `start_date`. In this case, there is an `employee_id` as well. And there are gaps in the sequence. The interval can vary.

The clustered index is on `employee_id, start_date`.
There is an unclustered index on `employee_id, end_date` that isn't used by the query below.

The current join from the current record to the previous contiguous record is (simplified):

```
SELECT *
FROM self AS current 
LEFT OUTER JOIN self AS previous 
ON previous.employee_id = current.employee_id
AND DATEADD(d, 1, previous.end_date) = current.start_date
```

There is a Seek Predicate on the employee_id. The `DATEADD()` is nonSARGable and stops the `end_date` index being used, so the join from `start_date` to `end_date` is a non-indexed Predicate.

Is there a way to get the `start_date` to `end_date` join to use an index? Either by clever indexing, a view or by rewriting the query?

I'm still on SQL Server 2008 R2, but please feel free to use the latest version in the answers.

Comment: Why does the `end date` have to be **the day before** the next record's `start_date`? Why can't it be exactly the next record's start_date? Looks like you could use indexes more efficiently then. I think that is the flaw in the design (that's what happens when one likes `BETWEEN` instead of inclusive-exclusive range checks. Related: **[What do `BETWEEN` and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)**

Comment: I agree that sounds like a good idea, but I'd have to do more background reading on temporal tables to be sure. An article I was reading yesterday seemed to imply that was a bad idea. But anyway, this is a mature product and I can't change it now.

Comment: Perhaps a computed persisted column like `next_start_date = DATEADD(d, 1, end_date)` and an NCI on `(employee_id, next_start_date)` might help then. Or an indexed view. I guess someone more focused on SQL Server can give better insight.

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines. I'll give it a go tonight and report back.

Comment: Also, I edited the tags, adding the tag for 2016 besides the 2008R2, although it's not released yet. I hear it has some additional temporal functionalities added: [Temporal Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn935015.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypercube's answer in the comments is spot-on.  You want a half-open interval, where end-date is *exclusive*.  In mathematical terms, it's `[start-date, end-date)`.  Then your joins are rock-solid equijoins, with no tap dancing on computed indexes or whatnot.

I see in your reply that you can't change the table, meaning of course you'll have to work around the design mistake.  I thought I'd just leave you a note explaining why the seemingly weird exclusive end-date is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM self AS current 
LEFT OUTER JOIN self AS previous 
ON previous.employee_id = current.employee_id
AND DATEADD(d, 1, previous.end_date) = current.start_date

and previous.start_date <> current.start_date
```

or if has to be less

```
and previous.start_date <  current.start_date
```

or if can isolate on prior

```
and previous.start_date = LAG (current.start_date, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY current.employee_id ORDER BY current.start_date DESC)
```